# TP4054 Battery Charging IC - Weak Pulldown / TriState Output

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, tri-state

I'm playing around with a TP4054, which is battery charging IC -- and I didn't know what I was doing when I added it to a sample board.  The CHRG pin is similiar to the Microchip MCP battery charging ICs, I think they call it the STATUS pin on the PIC parts.

I didn't read the datasheet in English, and I assumed it was not a tristate output for the CHRG pin (which basically goes high, low, or high impedance).  I thought it was just a AC present high signal, or no AC present low signal.

I'm confused about one state in the datasheet.  With no AC present, the chip is high impedance.  With AC present and charging, drives low.

With AC present and battery charged -- I don't get it what is happening...

[TP4054 Datasheet translated to English](https://www.piekarz.pl/pl/pdf.php?id=30089)

Here is the description of the CHRG pin:

"Open-Drain Charge Status
Output. When the battery is charging, the
 pin is pulled low by an internal
N-channel MOSFET. When the charge cycle
is completed, a weak pull-down of
approximately 20µA is connected to the
pin, indicating an “AC present” condition.
When the TP4054 detects an under voltage
lockout condition, is forced high
impedance."

Two questions:

1)
What exactly is the "weak pull-down of approximately 20µA"?  What does that mean?  How is that different from being pulled to ground when it is fully charging?

I originally had an internal pull-up on this CHRG pin, assuming it just pulls low when it is charging but this weak pull-down is monkeying with my MCU logic levels as it no longer reads as a low.  What exactly is happening here?

2)
When no voltage is detected, the CHRG pin goes high impedance -- meaning it becomes an input.  I've seen people recommend you built a voltage divider from VCC, and use an ADC which will read whatever voltage the divider makes when the CHRG pin is high impedance.  But what happens with this weak pull-down condition with the divider network?

Comment: if 5V then 20uA appears like 50k to gnd.  so 100k pullup gives 2/3Vcc when charge completed and Vcc if no AC and 0V if charging

Comment: So if you applied an internal pull-up on the CHRG pin line -- you'd get VCC at high impedance, 2/3 VCC (or whatever partial) with battery charged, and 0V if charging. 

You could use an ADC and you can see all three states? 

They have some kind of divider network (which I discovered in this English datasheet) -- I need to noodle how that thing works based on this.

Comment: So when the weak pull down activates, it forms a divider network?  Is the hint here they expect you to use a pull-up, because it is an open-drain?

Comment: yes if you want,  an LED with series R to V+

Comment: Got it.  Thanks,  I've never seen  that weak pull down in the IC to tri-state the output.  Live and learn...  I can probably figure out their divider logic to read the levels without using an ADC.